# DataBind based on Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataSource assigned to a DropDownList (DD2) that has a WHERE clause specified by the contents of another DropDownList (DD1). When I change the DD1, however, that DD2 does not reload its data. Is there a way to get DD2 to reload when DD1 is changed?

I've tried:

```
protected void DD1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DD2.DataBind();
}
```

But this appears to do nothing.

Comment: How are you defining the data source for DD2?

Comment: Through the designer, I'm simply assigning it to the DropDownList component. In that, I specify a WHERE clause that points to the selected value of DD1.

Comment: Have you set `autopostback="true"` in DD1 definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic of setting the DD2 `DataSource` and DD2 `DataBind()` to a new function and call that instead. Your problem is likely that the datasource is getting incorrectly set.

```
protected void DD2Bind()
{
    DD2.DataSource = //fetch data source
    DD2.DataBind();
}

protected void DD1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DD2Bind();
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this by setting DataSource to the SqlDataSource object I created in the designer, but I get the following error: `Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DD2'.  Remove one definition.` This seems to be because I already set the definition on DD2 in the designer.

Comment: @rar Could you include some code on how you are populating DD2?

Comment: There is no code for the initial population. It is done by assigning the DataSource in the Designer.

Comment: DataSourceID seems to be set by the initial setup I do. I managed to fix the issue with this code:
       `DD2.DataSourceID = null; DD2.Items.Clear(); DD2.DataSource = SqlDataSourceDD2; DD2.DataBind();`

Comment: @rar hopefully you'll centralize the binding like I showed instead of populating the DDL twice... or two different ways.

Comment: If I remove the SqlDataSource on the DropDownList itself, then when I populate the list using the method you demonstrated above, the list is populated with `System.Data.DataRowView`...

Comment: @rar possibly just need to set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

Comment: I just discovered that. As a very interesting case, the first time I set DD1, it still shows `System.Data.DataRowView`, but the second time and on, it displays the proper data. I just have to see when this is being called, I suppose./

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it - I was calling DataBind() before setting the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` so it wasn't actually setting those until after the first binding.